# Animation ends abruptly. How do I make this smooth?

Tags: swiftui

I have this code on ContentView

```
@State var animation: Bool = false


MyControl()
  .scaleEffect(animation ? 1.3 : 1)
  .animation(Animation.default.repeatCount(4, autoreverses: true))
```

Later on the code a button toggles the variable animation.

The result is

[image]

The end is abrupt and the final state is not the initial.

I want the view to scale up and down fast. Start with scale 1, scales up to 1.3 and back to 1, four times and ends with 1.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set autoreverses to false. It will keep the view at its last stopping point .